# Testing connectivity using API key in the header using Flask and PyMongo

Tags: rest, api, flask, pymongo

My server has to ensure the connectivity by receiving the request with API Key in the header from the client. I am finding it difficult to incorporate this using Flask decorator.

1. We provided API key to our Client which will be used to receiving the request.
2. When every request is made, we check and authenticate the Client for posting updates into our database.
3. The Swagger API definition has the parameter of API key located in Header which needs to be implemented using the Flask Decorator and corresponding function.

I have written the following Flask app code. And when It comes to receiving the API in the header, I am failing to rectify this server Error.

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, url_for, request, session, redirect,jsonify
from flask_pymongo import PyMongo
import json
from bson.json_util import dumps
import bcrypt
import os
from binascii import hexlify


app = Flask(__name__)

app.config['MONGO_DBNAME'] = 'demo'
app.config['MONGO_URI'] = 'mongodb://xxxx:xxxx@xxxxxxx.mlab.com:57158/demo'

mongo = PyMongo(app)


@app.route('/addapi')
def addapi():
    users = mongo.db.users
    api_key=users.insert({"name":"apikey","X-API-Key":"69222c9b-7858-4eef-a218-039c8cd2bc6e"})
    return 'API Key stored'

@app.route('/test/<string:apikey_given_by_user_in_the_header>',methods=['GET'])
"""I have a doubt in the above line that How Can I receive the API Key in the header and check if that is available in my database. This is for testing the connectivity using the Valid API Key."""

def test(apikey_given_by_user_in_the_header):
    users=mongo.db.users
    api_record=users.find_one({'name':"apikey"})
    actual_API_key=api_record['X-API-Key']
    if actual_API_key==apikey_given_by_user_in_the_header
        return "API is available"
    return "Invalid API Key"
```

The Swagger API definition for Parameter is as below:

```
"parameters": [
                    {
                        "name": "X-API-Key",
                        "in": "header",
                        "required": true,
                        "type": "string"
                    },
```

Can You kindly advise How can I incorporate this API key authentication where the Client will have to input the API key based upon which my server needs to check and authenticate? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> To access incoming request data, you can use the global request object.

when client send a request with header which you need, you can access incoming request header `request.headers`, header is dictionary like object:

```
from flask import request

@app.route('/api')
def home():
    key = request.headers.get('API-Key')
    print(key)
    return 'Got %s key'%key
```

To test with curl or httpie

```
$ http get localhost:port/api API-Key:key-goes-here12458
$ curl -H "API-Key:key-goes-here12458" localhost:port/api
```

Comment: Thanks very much , Your guidance helped me a lot and saved lot of working hours.